# Scrape GIS data to find sites that match certain criteria

Tags: qgis

I'm an architect (the building kind) that has been practicing open source architecture for a number of years.

All our 'blueprints' are open source and hosted on github.

We have a number of projects we've done in the past, residences, multiple family, etc.

Since we spent so much time developing these projects, it would be awesome if we could redevelopment them again, on another similar site.

The problem is, however, to manually find a site with the same (or similar) criteria (size of lot, setbacks, topography changes, etc.) as the original site would be near impossible.

Would be awesome if we could search/scrape GIS data to narrow down a list of candidate sites that matched the characteristics/criteria of the original site.

Relatively doable?

Perhaps a QGIS plugin?

Comment: Your assumption here is that lot size, setbacks, and topography have been calculated for every possible lot. This is a *huge* assumption, and probably untrue in even the counties with the most sophisticated GIS infrastructure. You can't scrape data that does not exist, and even if it did, it's not likely to easily accessible, and would vary in volume and quality and format by county. I'd categorize this as Relatively Impossible.

Comment: This process is usually called "site selection" or "site assessment". It's very doable in GIS, but the process isn't one size fits all, it depends on what you're building and what exactly is important to your selection process. There isn't one plugin that will do it for, say, building a house and also for siting an office building. Also, the data that you want to "scrape" doesn't necessarily exist. Tax parcel data is very spotty across the USA, some counties have great data, some have paper maps. Topography data is widely available, but for elevation *changes*, you'll need to process the data.

Comment: Speaking as a county cadastral specialist myself, I can tell you that some of this data can be calculated from a parcel layer, some is entered into our assessment database by non-GIS staff, some is from non-county data sources, and some is not maintained at all. In other counties, the data may only be maintained as static map annotations, rather than feature attribution. As @Vince notes, it's really spotty, just in my county and surrounding ones, to say nothing of anywhere else. I'd say just collect any data you can and see what you can do with it.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the perspective--makes sense.

Comment: @JoshC, are there any standardizing initiatives out there, that you know of, that are looking at ways to standardize this type of data?

I could see this being a valuable standard, if it existed.

Comment: Oh, I really wish there were. The nearest thing I can think of is [Wisconsin's Statewide Parcel Layer](https://www.sco.wisc.edu/parcels/data/). Not sure if other states have done this, though.

Comment: Awesome, i just so happen to be in Wisconsin! Did you know that, or was that just coincidental?